# python subprocess run by one by

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

i have some sort of processes :

```
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script1.py')],shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script2.py')],shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script3.py')],shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script4.py')],shell=True)
```

i want to each one starts after the previous process completely finish.
i mean

```
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script2.py')],shell=True)
```

starts after

```
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script1.py')],shell=True)
```

completly finished, and for others the same. this is cause previous scripts has output that it is used by next script.
thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [wait()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) for each one to finish, like this :

```
sp1 = subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script1.py'],shell=True)
sp1.wait()

sp2 = subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script2.py'],shell=True)
sp2.wait()

sp3 = subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script3.py'],shell=True)
sp3.wait()

sp4 = subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script4.py'],shell=True)
sp4.wait()
```

Or in shorter way :

```
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script1.py'],shell=True).wait()
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script2.py'],shell=True).wait()
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script3.py'],shell=True).wait()
subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 script4.py'],shell=True).wait()
```

Comment: There is a paranthesis mistake here : (['python2.7 script1.py')], which should be corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

> Run the command described by *args*. Wait for command to complete, then return the `returncode` attribute.

In your example:

```
subprocess.call(['python2.7 script1.py'],shell=True)
subprocess.call(['python2.7 script2.py'],shell=True)
subprocess.call(['python2.7 script3.py'],shell=True)
subprocess.call(['python2.7 script4.py'],shell=True)
```